# How to stop Slick Carousel on Hover

Tags: javascript, html, hover, carousel, slick.js

I have the following code for a continuous horizontal slow scroll using Slick Carousel. This is all working great, except when I hover the carousel i'd like it to immediately stop scrolling. At the moment because of the `speed` being `13000` it takes 13 seconds for it to stop scrolling once hovered.

Any ideas how to achieve this? Also I'd like the carousel's speed to go back to `13000` on mouseleave.

Thanks all.

```
$('.my_slider').slick({
   slidesToShow: 5,
   slidesToScroll: 1,
   autoplay: true,
   autoplaySpeed: 1,
   speed: 13000,
   pauseOnHover: true,
   cssEase: 'linear',
   dots: false,
   infinite: true,
   adaptiveHeight: true,
   arrows: false,
});
```

**UPDATE**

Ive tried appending a `mouseenter` event listener to the main function, but no luck.

```
$('.my_slider').slick({
  ... SETINGS HERE...
}).on('mouseenter', function(){
   $(this).slick({
      speed: 100,
   })
})
```

Comment: Virtually all image sliders will slide the image till the left edge of the image lands even with the left edge of the DIV frame. FreeMode slider option is the likely only way to make the images land anywhere, but it defeats your autoplay. See "swiperJS" demo for freemode. 

Alternate: Look at jsfiddle under a "/nstanard/a0xyqsjv/" for an example of a "Pause button". Works on slick JS 1.5.9 max. Click slider image to start slider again. Hover on image to temp halt image at a slide. As noted above the left edge of image will stop when it lands at the left edge of the frame.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the autoplay speed to 13000, because it defines the change interval and set the speed to a lower value, for example 1000.

Comment: Yeah I have tried swapping both values. Then it scrolls once every 13 seconds.